# Detect facebook bot

Tags: php, facebook

I have a website where the staging site of this is secured by a basic auth. When facebook tries to access some elements, I would like to detect that and not use basic auth. Is there any way of knowing if facebook bot is sending the request? For example a custom HTTP header? Thanks.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/#scraperinfo

Comment: Anyone wants to downgrade this, please explain why first. Don't do it, just because you can.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more clear what you mean by "Facebook Bot"?  Do you mean the Crawler that scrapes information for Open Graph type stuff?  If so, you can find the list of IPs they use [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity/#facebook_scraper).

Comment: Sorry about the delay. I mean more about open Graph. For example for FB share, FB would run in and get more information about the page, which will mean FB needs to access the page. Basic auth would prevent it.